# How to send sender as usercontrol

Tags: asp.net

Created ascx file with three drop down control, on post back of each drop down sender is showing System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList, how to show it as usercontrol so i can find respective control value.

Answer (score 0):

Please, consider using updatepanel envolving both controls on the page that uses them, and handling the selectindexchange event on that same page (which will now not postback anymore).

go through this link

> https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/784836/how-to-bind-two-relative-drop-down-in-user-control

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, but no help.